# How to deal with students leaving the class for 10 min during the lecture?

Tags: etiquette, teaching

In the freshman classes I teach (the class is like 30-35 students), some students would step out the class for 10-15 minutes and come back. The class time is 1 hour and 15 min. This is always interrupting.

I have asked the class before that this is a poor classroom etiquette, you have 15 min between classes to do whatever you want, so if you leave the class during the lecture please do not come back. Yet, they still do it.

Anybody is facing similar situation? and how you deal with it?

Clarification: I made it clear in class that if you need to leave, please inform me in advance. Or if you have a medical condition that requires you to leave regularly, please let me know. My question is not about those cases

Comment: I would have to say that not every student has the luxury of being able to do what they want for 15 minutes after class. Sometimes it takes me a full 15 minutes just to walk to my next class.

Comment: How far is the restroom/toilet from the classroom? Is that what's taking so long, or are they smoking breaks?

Comment: For clarification, I think the question should also state whether being present in the class is compulsory to achieve some goal, or voluntary. That can have a significant effect on how far you can afford to deter students from attending the class. Also, is it the fact that someone is leaving the room and coming back (which I find questionable - adults should be able to cope with that; from what I have seen, it is commonplace in conferences and business meetings, too), or way *how* they do it that appears to be so interrupting to you?

Comment: How is it 'interrupting'?

Comment: @CapeCode The room doors are in the front of the class near the board. Someone is walking towards the door will be distracting, same when he comes back.

Comment: What country is this in?

Comment: To me it matters a lot whether the student makes an effort to be as unobtrusive as possible, given the physical layout of the room. For example, if I'm conducting a classroom discussion, and a student walks in front of me on their way out of the room, holding their cell phone, that's unacceptable, and I would call the student out on that. But if the student is pregnant and needs to pee every 30 minutes, and sidles out along a side aisle as unobtrusively as possible, I don't see how I could object.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Attendance contributes 5% of the grade, I take it at the beginning or at the end of the class. May be a possible solution is to start taking it at random times?!

Comment: Their loss. Unless they are walking on desks or something.

Comment: I remember having one lecture that ended very shortly after another lecture started, and I should have attended both. I thought it was better to leave one 10 minutes earlier (quietly, picking a seat close to the exit) than entering the other ten minutes late. Obviously if people take a cigarette break during your lecture, that would be very rude.

Comment: I would simply lock the door and consider that a lesson: There's no coming back if you leave. However, that may be yet another of the reasons why I've never and I'll never teach.

Comment: It may be a misunderstanding on the concept of the lecture on your site. When I was studying, the lectures were open and non-compulsory, so everyone could walk in and walk out as they wish. Any attempt to limit that freedom would be against the academic culture.

Comment: Missing information: what country is this in, what subject do you teach, what is your style (Socratic method? lecture from blackboard? slides? orally? from textbook?) How engaged are your students? Is your style boring or engaging? Have you asked them for suggestions on lecture format and breaks? instead of trying to force something on them. Why not ask *them* before asking here?

Comment: @Trylks when I was an exchange student in Denmark, a teacher would do precisely that 3-5 minutes after the lecture was scheduled to start. We witnessed one or two instances when a person arrived a bit late, but it was quite embarassing to interrupt the lecture and knock the door, so they never did it again.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

The existing answers seem to me extreme.  I don't think some sort of draconian blanket "leaving-the-room policy" is needed here.  I would suggest the following:

- For students leaving occasionally: **Ignore it.** They are adults and sometimes things in their lives may take higher priority than your class (e.g. going to the bathroom, feeling unwell, family emergencies, etc).  If it's distracting to you, well, deal with it.  It's a classroom, not a funeral, and you are a professional.  Take a breath and get back to teaching.
- If you see a particular student leaving often: **Have a private word with them to see if things are okay.**  They may have special circumstances that you don't know about (chronic illness is one distinct possibility).  Once you know their situation, you may be able to offer specific suggestions that will reduce the disruption and/or get them more engaged in the class.
- If, after talking to them, you are convinced they are just walking out from spite, and they won't stop: **Follow your institution's policy on disruptive students.**  Your department chair should have further guidance.  It may ultimately be necessary to drop them from the class.

A short break in the middle of a 75-minute class is a reasonable idea, but I would keep it very short: perhaps 1-2 minutes, enough to stand up and stretch, not more.  It should not significantly reduce the amount of time students spend on task.  (Otherwise, as mentioned above, you may encounter problems with your institution's authorities that your class does not provide as much instructional time as promised by its number of credit hours.  Moreover, some students will see it as wasted time and resent it.)  Better yet, break up the lecture with some other sort of productive activity (small group discussions, problem solving, etc).

I don't think it's appropriate to publicly shame students for poor etiquette, or shut them out of class if they leave.  You will unfairly punish students who legitimately need to step out for a few minutes, and anyone who is doing it from spite or boredom will just be further alienated.

Comment: I couldn't agree with this more - particularly with regard to illness etc. Even if a student appears otherwise healthy they may suffer from anxiety attacks or digestive problems, or even Thrombosis which would certainly require moving regularly! Don't ever shame a student without knowing their circumstances, you could do a lot of harm. Perhaps ask people who know they regularly need to leave, to sit themselves in the back corners?

Comment: Very good answer, except perhaps for the "use all of the 75 minutes" part. In my experience, many students (not to mention other people, like professors) can't or won't concentrate effectively for such a long, uninterrupted time. A 10-minute break in the middle might actually achieve _more_ learning.

Comment: @Thomas: It might, but at many places that is not a decision the instructor has the authority to make. My point is that, rather than including a long break during which students are not doing anything, you can break up the time by having them do something different. My feeling is that this will be more effective than 75 minutes of lecture, with or without a 10 minute break.

Comment: I agree that I've had > 1 hour lectures I don't really focus in, but for better or for worse that is well within the standards. My 3 hour classes had 10 minutes every hour (but they were an accelerated version of 3 50 minute classes so there's that) but have had up to 80 minute lectures no break.

Comment: @djechlin and others: Well, it takes a good teacher, and a good structure of the lecture to make a 75-minute lecture worth the time. We have 100-minute lectures here, and as a lecturer or assistant, I have to confess that it's not an easy job, but it can be done. As a student, I was well-know for simply falling asleep at some lectures, because the way it was done was beyond my capabilities. I wouldn't, however, encourage systematic breaks in the lectures, since it's very difficult to make such a break short enough.

Comment: @NateEldredge Where does a professor or lecturer not have the authority to stop lecturing for five to ten minutes and say "okay, stretch break"? North Korea?

Comment: @TylerH: I haven't found an official policy, but I'm pretty sure my (US, public) institution would frown on it.  We were recently warned about ensuring our classes met on every day scheduled.  With two 75-minute classes per week, a 10-minute break in each class is the equivalent of cancelling two full weeks of classes in a semester.  I think 1 minute sounds like a stretch break.  10 minutes is more like a "smoke break" and may create the perception that the instructor just doesn't feel like preparing a full class worth of material.

Comment: @NateEldredge I agree that 10 minutes is pretty long for a 1 to 2 hour class, but I think two to five is pretty reasonable. It allows people to stretch, maybe get water if there's a water fountain outside the classroom, pee if they *really* have to, check over/catch up on notes, ask the professor a question about something without waiting for it become entirely irrelevant/forgotten, lets students check their phones, refreshes them and their attention spans for when you "start" the class back, etc. The benefits are myriad!

Answer (score 33):

Have a 10-minute break in the middle of the lecture. (E.g., 35min lecture + 10min break + 30min lecture = 1h 15min in total.)

1h 15min is far too much without any breaks. There are plenty of studies that show that students do not really pay attention to the lectures more than for maybe 20-30 minutes in the beginning of the lecture (and for a short period of time right before the lecture ends), so by telling *everyone* to take a 10-minute break you are likely to *improve* the learning outcomes (even if you have got slightly less time for teaching).

Comment: You are reducing the number of credits this way of that course! You cannot just throw 20 min away from class official time per week

Comment: @Moa: You do not get credits for sitting in a classroom, you get credits for learning things.

Comment: Allowing students to leave in the middle of the class may be disturbing to the class time. They will need 5 to 10 minutes after that short break to come back to the class, one by one... How should an instructor control the students coming back to the class exactly in that break time? Then he may have problem with organizing the class after that break. This way, he will miss about 20 minutes of his class. I think freshman students are grown enough to sit one hour in the class and pay enough attention to the content.

Comment: Dear Jukka, this is a credit hour system. You must deliver lectures for certain period of time per week. Not doing so, means you are not doing your job.

Comment: @Moa: Don't you have the freedom to make the most effective use (= best learning outcomes) of the time that is allocated for your lectures?

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent: It is not so difficult. E.g., the first lecture starts at 10:15, ends at 10:50, the second lecture starts at 11:00, ends at 11:30, that's it. Everyone is there on time for the second lecture, just like they are there on time for the first lecture.

Comment: @JukkaSuomela I like the idea but who guarantees that *Everyone is there on time for the second lecture*?

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent: The same guy who guarantees that everyone is there on time when for the first lecture. Every student is of course responsible for making sure that they are there on time for the lecture.

Comment: And yes, of course sometimes some students come a bit late, but handling this is not really related to the break. One thing that helps is that you as a lecturer stick to the schedule. You start your lecture precisely when it is supposed to start. Usually students feel a bit embarrassed if they come late and disturb the lecture; next time they will pay more attention to the schedule.

Comment: I almost always include a break in the middle of a 75 minute class, but it doesn't need to be 10 minutes to be effective, for the students I have. Just 2-3 minutes works fine. I start again at the announced time even if some students aren't back yet.  At each break I strongly encourage the students to stand up, even if they aren't going anywhere.  The break does seem to make a significant different in their ability to focus during the second half of a long class.

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph, -1 for the second (so net 0); I find 1.25 hour lectures quite easy to sit through.  However, especially for longer lectures (e.g. 4 hour summer classes, or 2-3 hour night classes), a short break can be very rejuvenating.

Comment: _1h 15min is far too much without any breaks_ — [citation needed]

Comment: I find it quite literally scary that there seem to be universities where an instructor cannot decide on her/his own whether to have a short break in class or not.

Comment: @xLeitix If you add a break and finish later, the break before tohe next lecture could be eaten just by going the the other lecture room and students may have no time to relax before that one.

Comment: @JeffE is (maybe accidentally) right: you could give a reference on the time frame. IIRC there are studies (with adults) that show that lecture times above 45min are mostly useless.

Comment: @JeffE [Citation Provided](http://ixil.izt.uam.mx/pd/lib/exe/fetch.php/ib:modconduccion:the_change_up_in_lectures.pdf) It appears that 15-20 minutes is how long you can go before your brain zones out. I won't say that 1h15 is too long, but it is getting up there in terms of brain drain. Most of my lectures that I've taken always take a break at the mid-way mark for 5 minutes for the 1.5hr sessions, or every 50 minutes for the longer sessions.

Comment: When-I-was-a-student lessons used to be 2 hours long each. Should not be a problem, unless you make a 2 hour long monotonous monologue. That would not exactly be a problem either, but more of a solution for insomnia.

Comment: @VladimirF Nobody mentioned finishing later; the point was whether instructors should be allowed to decide how to use the time allocated to their lectures most efficiently (e.g. 75 minutes without breaks vs. 30 min + 10 min break + 35 min).

Answer (score 5):

Not to offend your teaching methods or style, but perhaps you should ask yourself why the students are leaving in the first place. I would suggest talking to one of them outside of class and asking honestly if there's something you can do to help their learning experience that is non-disruptive to the other students.

I had a professor who was brilliant but not good at teaching because he had difficulties relating to his students. Because of this, several students would leave for 10-20 minutes at a time in the middle of class because they felt they weren't getting anything out of the class. If your students need more stimulation during lecture, try switching up your teaching style once in a while. Include a little bit of interactivity with trivia or jeopardy-style extra credit in the middle of class to keep everybody participating and excited to learn.

Comment: "Because of this, several students would leave for 10-20 minutes at a time in the middle of class because they felt they weren't getting anything out of the class." Hm, but why only for 10-20 minutes and not for longer or forever? If they weren't getting anything out of the class, I don't understand why they would come back at all. To me this sounds more like they deliberately decided to perturb the class as much as possible, seeing that they can get nothing out of it.

Answer (score 4):

> In the classes I teach some students would step out the class for 10-15 minutes and come back. This is always interrupting.

Consider the following questions:

- Can you rearrange your classroom so it's less distracting (door in the back rather than front or sides)?
- Who is it distracting, you, or the other students?
- Is it the same students?
- Does it happen every day in every class, or is it more rare than that?
- Are several people leaving and entering at random times throughout the period, or is it just two interruptions per class when it does happen?

The students are adults.  They are free to make decisions about their time.  Honestly, 1.25 hours isn't too long to expect an adult to sit and listen to a presentation or lecture.  They do it all the time at any other performance, be it a movie theater, play, or otherwise.

You should first consider whether the interruptions are truly preventing the students from learning.  If the only problem is that you are interrupted, then honestly you need to change so such interruptions don't bother you any more.

If you can alter the layout of the classroom, then a physical change might improve the situation.

Finally, if you truly feel that these interruptions are unacceptable and cannot be accommodated then you have the following options:

1. Talk to those who leave.  Do it after class every time they leave.  "You understand that you are expected to attend the whole class period. If this was an emergency, then I can excuse it."
2. Start giving out useful hints for upcoming tests/projects/etc.  Save them for the time when people leave.
3. Start making it an issue of attendance. "If you leave during class I will mark you absent." Alternately every three times they leave they get counted absent for one day.
4. Start making it an issue of grades.  "In-class attendance without breaks is a requirement for this course. If you do not attend, or you interrupt class to leave or exit between the start and end of class, it will impact your grade in the following ways."
5. Start giving 5-10 minute pop quizzes.  Keep some handy you can use at a moment's notice when people leave.
6. Grow up.  You are an adult.  Your students are adults. You and your students can ignore the exit/entrance of a student and continue on without remark or change in pace.  There's no need to punish those who leave.  Make your presentations as informative and interesting as possible, then move forward and ignore those that leave or enter at inappropriate times.

Wasting your time and energy getting upset will only hurt you. Train your patience and ability to carry on in the face of adversity, and you'll become a more effective instructor.

Comment: "You are an adult. Your students are adults." Sure, but even adults get distracted by too loid noise and/or lots of movement. You cannot ignore it totally even as an adult or there wouldn't be do not disturb signs in libraries. So I kind of doubt it doesn't affect the other adult students and doesn't lower their concentration at all. There is probably some balance needed.

Answer (score 2):

### Punishment

> Attendance contributes 5% of the grade, I take it at the beginning or at the end of the class. May be a possible solution is to start taking it at random times?

Others already mentioned that students can have valid reasons to leave your class for 10 minutes, among other [*]:

- health issues (anxiety issues, bladder problems, a bad back, etc.)
- pregnancy
- family emergencies (which can be quite regular in some cases)

Punishing them for these issues would not be the right thing to do, and it might very well **violate your schools non-discrimination policy**.

You should also keep this in mind when talking about the issue in class (because it can - depending on the situation - easily come across as public shaming and thus 1. discourage students from taking your class and - again - 2. violate the non-discrimination policy).

<sub>[*] If your students are leaving in small groups, these reasons could also explain that (good friends helping with an anxiety attack for example).</sub>

### Suggestions on handling this

**Ignore it**. There are enough valid reasons that students might step out[*], and honestly, non of them are any of your business. And **the students are already punished**: They missed part of the class, and possibly cannot follow the rest of the class that well because of missing information, so they have to work at home to catch up.

If you still want to take action:

- try to apply for a room that has exits at the back
- analyze your material: are there parts of your class that are boring/unnecessary? students might be leaving because of this
- create a questionnaire asking about this, which the students can answer anonymously

If you want to talk with the students about it:

- do it privately and individually
- apologize for bringing it up in class in front of everyone, suggesting that they have poor etiquette, and asking them to not come back
- don't ask for their reasons, or at least accept "private" as a valid answer
- ask how you can help them (for example, provide them with a seat closest to the exit)

<sub>[*] This is still true if some students step out just because they want to smoke. It is not ok to punish the students with good reasons along with the students with bad reasons.</sub>

Comment: Or bring it up in class and ask the other students what they think.  Do *they* think it's disruptive? Would they generally appreciate a break halfway through? Is there a problem with the venue (e.g. bad air circulation which is ignored by some, but highly distractive for some others)?

Comment: By punishment you're creating extra rules to check, and you may violate the academic rules that the lectures must not be compulsory.

Answer (score 2):

At my university, there were classrooms where the outer door handle locked after class started. If you left, you couldn't return until someone let you in. To be clear, students could leave, but not return without assistance. 
This approach worked very well for interruption deterrence.

Comment: we have those doors in some rooms as well, and in my experience, they cause quite a distraction. Students leave just as often, but they cannot just sneak quietly back in, but have to knock, disturbing the whole class, and the student closest to the door, who has to stand up to open the door.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO grading based on attendance is not optimum.  If a student who is there 50% of the time can learn everything a student who is there 100% of the time can, do they really need to be punished for it?

A compromise view might be: base the grade on various factors, like exams, attendance, participation, homework, and what not; with each student being given the option of an alternative weighing: mostly exams.  If someone then does poorly on exams *because* they missed part of the class, that's their problem.  But if they do well, why worry about seat time?

One thing I definitely dislike: someone comes in late and the instructor stops speaking and waits for the latecomer to sit down and settle in.  And then complain about *"what the latecomer did to disrupt the class"* (guilt tripping).  I think the instructor should just keep talking and let the chips fall where they may.  (The latecomer/break taker must not of course be so loud as to make it impossible for the instructor to be heard.)

Answer (score -2):

The statement

> if you leave the class during the lecture please do not come back

is ambiguous. If they leave class are they allowed to come back or not? The best solution in my opinion is not to create rules like this since it effectively backs you into a corner. Some things, like being respectful of classmates, need firm rules and require you to enforce them. Things like bathroom breaks probably do not, but if your ability to teach really depends on students not interrupting class, then you need to do something about it. the best thing would be to change your teaching style such that interruptions are not hugely distracting. If you cannot change your teaching style and students coming and going is hurting the rest of the students, then you need to do something about it.

I suggest at the start of the next class you clarify your original statement with:

> If you choose to leave class during the lecture you will not be allowed to return.

Then the first time someone gets up to leave, interrupt the lecture and remind them they will not be allowed to return. The reason I suggest two warnings is this is a change in behaviour. If they leave and attempt to come back, stop your lecture and tell them to leave. Do not resume your lecture until they leave. Hopefully it will not come to it, but if necessary call the campus police to have them escorted from the classroom. One sacrificial student will probably be enough to regain control. The key is if you see students coming and going as a critical issue for you teaching you need to take control of the situation. Hopefully, you can modify your teaching to handle students coming and going.

Comment: Campus police seems like overkill (if I were a student in the class watching this unfold, I would probably drop that class ASAP)

Comment: @ff524 I think it is unlikely to come to that, but if a student won't leave, then you are in a difficult situation.

Comment: Moreover, there are countries where there is no such thing as a campus police. But, in the end, do you really want to lose the respect of your students by calling a higher authorithy for something you should be able to deal with?

Comment: So, just to make things clear, are you proposing that the students should urinate on the floor or miss half the class? Yes, of course students should plan bathroom breaks between classes but sometimes plans go wrong, people get delayed, the cleaners pick a bad time to clean or there's a queue. Forbidding students to return to the classroom is draconian and ridiculous. Creating a huge disruption out of a small disruption is counterproductive and, frankly, stupid.